# Smart quotes creating a problem with anonymos user role

Tags: views

I have create a view. The content of the view loads fine when logged in as admin. But in some of the content when you copy paste from MS Work, certain characters changes.

For e.g. `"` becomes `“`

Now the content which contains such characters is not displayed in that view.

But when logged in as admin, I see those content. What could be the problem ?

I checked using devel. The number of results which are fetch is different. Those with special characters are not fetched when viewing as anonymous user.

Comment: Could it be that the content in question is unpublished? When different results are returned for an admin it's generally an access issue, which suggests the content is not viewable. Have you got any node access modules installed?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it's hard to tell exactly's going on but there's a couple things that come to mind:

- Copying and pasting from MS Word/other rich text editors is notoriously problematic and both TinyMCE and CKEditor have built-in settings for pasting data from Word & stripping the extra formatting
- In case you're not using any WYSIWYG you should always paste your code in Notepad or another plain-text editor and then re-copy it to lose the extra formatting
- Finally, I don't really think it applies to viewing content at all but the visibility thing might have to do with the text-format used in the body field, it's common to edit content using Full HTML and then users without access to it (only Filtered HTML for example) can't edit it

Comment: My two cents: maybe somehow "Smart quotes" force using Full HTML mode and only admin is allowed to do so? Or some other module filters "potentially dangerous content" for all but admin?

Comment: The problem is just with the display. The strange thing is I can view it properly when logged in using admin but not without login.

Comment: Let me know any other information is needed.